# In the infinite Cartesian product in Enderton's *Elements*, how is $H$ a function if $H(i)$ has multiple elements?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I know there are very similar questions about the definition of infinite Cartesian products, but I haven't been able to find an answer to my specific problem, which I know must be extremely basic and fundamental. The definition in *Elements of Set Theory* is:

Let $I$ be an index set, and $H$ a function whose domain includes $I$. Then, for each $i$ in $I$ we have the set $H(i)$; we want the product of the $H(i)$'s for all $i \in I$. We define:
$$
\times_{i \in I} H(i)= \{f \mid f \text{ is a function with domain } I \text{ and } (\forall i \in I)f(i) \in H(i) \}.
$$

A later example makes it clear that each $H(i)$ is a set with multiple elements—for example, with $I= \omega$, the Cartesian product consists of various "threads" connecting individual choices from $H(0)$, $H(1)$, $H(2)$... I think I'm understanding that concept fine, but I don't see how any individual set $H(i)$ could have more than one element, since $H$ being a function directly implies that, when applied to any individual element of its domain, must point to one-and-only-one element in the range. Where am I slipping up?

Comment: $H(i)$ **is** one object: that object is some set. The fact that the set $H(i)$ in general has more than one element is irrelevant.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I'm so sorry, there's something I'm just not getting here, and it's really frustrating because I think I usually get these things. So in the sense that a function is just a set of ordered pairs $\langle x,y \rangle$ where each x has only one y, we're talking about, possibly, in a finite example, a set of ordered pairs like $\langle 0, \{ 3,7,8 \} \rangle $ or $ \langle 1, \{ 5,7,9 \} \rangle $ and such, with the added possibility that the $y$ aspect is infinite? But then I don't see how to make a Cartesian product of such things. Could you give a finite example that I could try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here’s a small, finite example. Let $I=\{0,1\}$, $X=\{a,b,c\}$, and $Y=\{\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta\}$. Let $\mathscr{H}=\{X,Y\}$, and define $H:I\to\mathscr{H}$ by setting $H(0)=X$ and $H(1)=Y$. Then $\prod_{i\in I}H(i)$ is the set of functions $f:I\to\bigcup_{i\in I}H(i)$ such that $f(i)\in H(i)$ for each $i\in I$. One of these functions is $f=\{\langle 0,b\rangle,\langle 1,\gamma\rangle\}$: $f(0)=b\in H(0)$, and $f(1)=\gamma\in H(1)$. This function corresponds to the ordered pair $\langle b,\gamma\rangle\in X\times Y$, and if you write out all $12$ members of $\prod_{i\in I}H(i)$, you’ll find that each corresponds in a natural way to an ordered pair in $X\times Y$: the map

$$\prod_{i\in I}H(i)\to X\times Y:\{\langle 0,x\rangle,\langle 1,y\rangle\}\mapsto\langle x,y\rangle$$

is clearly a bijection, and in practice it almost never matters which way we think about the Cartesian product of $X$ and $Y$.

The intuitive idea behind the Cartesian product is that it contains exactly one point for each possible choice of one point from each factor. There is one point in the plane $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$ for each choice of a real number from the first factor and a real number from the second factor. In the plane we can identify the choices that make up a point in the plane by using an ordered pair: the first member of the pair is the choice from the first factor, and the second member of the pair is the choice from the second factor. More generally, for Cartesian products of $n$ sets we usually think of the elements as $n$-tuples and identify the element picked from the $k$-th set by making it the $k$-th entry in the $n$-tuple identifying the element. That idea still more or less works for products of countably infinitely many sets, if we think of a sequence $$\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle=\langle x_0,x_1,x_2,\ldots\rangle$$ as a sort of infinite tuple.

For products of uncountably many sets, though, that approach just won’t work. For instance, if for each real number $r$ we have a set $X_r$, and we want to form the Cartesian product of the sets $X_r$, we need something more general than *position in a tuple* to keep track of the coordinate of a point in the product. In that case we say that a point of the Cartesian product $\prod_{r\in\Bbb R}X_r$ is a function $x$ with domain $\Bbb R$ such that $f(r)\in X_r$ for each $r\in\Bbb R$. This $f$ is a set of ordered pairs, $\{\langle r,f(r)\rangle:r\in\Bbb R\}$, so it does pick out one point, $f(r)$, from each of the sets $X_r$. And being a function with domain $\Bbb R$, the index set, it keeps track automatically of where each of these coordinates $f(r)$ came from: $f(r)$ came from $X_r$, the $r$-th factor set.

Comment: Wonderful, you are a saint. I have a much clearer picture of this now. Just a couple of clarifying points: in your map, the $\langle 1,r \rangle $ ordered pair should be $\langle 1,y \rangle $, right? And so, if I'm understanding you correctly, the payoff of this somewhat more complicated Cartesian product structure is that (assuming the Axiom of Choice), it allows us to set up $i$-tuples even involving uncountably many sets? Or is that impossible no matter what?

Comment: @PatMuchmore: Yep, definitely a typo; looks like I triggered the wrong hand. It doesn’t really give us $i$-tuples for infinite cardinalities $i$, but it gives us something that serves the same purpose of letting us identify the ‘pieces’ and associate them with their source sets.